# Buttons in JDialog not clickable when it's on top of other two modal popups

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jwindow

I have a swing application.I have a Window which should be showed on clicking of few text fields.(It's like a virtual keyboard with few keys).
That window is created using

```
Window wdw= new JDialog();
```

It's set to modal as well. `((JDialog) wdw).setModal(true);`

The keys have mouse listener added. On clicking and holding of keys, it shows another JDialog with showing extra few buttons.

Below is the method to create that window which is called on press and hold of a key.

```
private void createPopupKeys(MouseEvent e) {
    JButton keyBtn = (JButton)e.getSource();
    Window parentWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(keyBtn);
    Window dialog = new JDialog(parentWindow);
    dialog.setFocusable(true);
    dialog.setFocusableWindowState(true);

    JPanel contP = (JPanel)((JDialog) dialog).getContentPane();
    contP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 40));
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    String[][] popupKeys = {{"123","123","123"},
                            {"124","124","196"},
                            {"125","125","197"},
                            {"126","126","198"},
                            };
    for (int i = 0; i < popupKeys.length; i++) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(popupKeys[i][0]);
        btn.setActionCommand(popupKeys[i][2]);
        btn.setName("popupkey"+i);
        btn.addMouseListener(this);
        btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        btn.setFocusable(false);
        btn.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 14));
        pnl.add(btn);
    }

    pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 40));
    contP.add(pnl);
            dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    Point loc = keyBtn.getLocationOnScreen();
    dialog.setLocation(loc.x - 20 , loc.y - 50);
    dialog.pack();

    dialog.setVisible(true);

    dialog.addWindowFocusListener(windowListener);
    dialog.addWindowListener(windowListener);
}

WindowAdapter windowListener = new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        JDialog dialog = (JDialog) e.getSource();
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        dialog.dispose();
    }
};
```

In normal window, when I click on a text field, the modal window is opened, and on press and hold of a key, the new popup key dialog is opened and all are clickable.

But when I click on a text field in a modal popup, the window is opened and on press and hold of a key, the popup keys are displayed also. But no buttons in popup keys are clickable.

What could be the reason? And whats the solution?

Comment: Could you share all class?

Comment: Your code has the line btn.addMouseListener(this); what the listener is here?

Comment: For better help sooner post a [MCVE].

Comment: Please add the MouseListener implemetation for  line **btn.addMouseListener(this)** in  the question

Comment: Could you post an explainatory question rather than descriptive. And add screenshots for the problem.

Comment: Please post full code.